# OVER_QUERY_LIMIT in simple SPGooglePlacesAutocompleteQuery request

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-places

I'm trying to create simple autocomplete UI widget:

```
self.autocompleteQuery = [[SPGooglePlacesAutocompleteQuery alloc] initWithApiKey:[GlobalConfig sharedInstance].kGoogleBrowserKey];
self.autocompleteQuery.language = kFFAutocompleteQueryLanguage;
self.autocompleteQuery.types = SPPlaceTypeAddress;
self.autocompleteQuery.location = [FFAppDataHelper coordinatesForMoscow];
self.autocompleteQuery.radius = [GlobalConfig sharedInstance].kMoscowRadius;
self.autocompleteQuery.countryCode = @"RU";
```

Then I want to get all values for input string from UITextField on 'valueChanged' event:

```
self.autocompleteQuery.input = [streetName stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
[self.autocompleteQuery fetchPlaces:^(NSArray *places, NSError *error) {
    [self loaderStopAnimating];

    if (places) {
      //do some stuff
    } else {
        FFError *detectedError = [FFError errorWithNSError:error];
        [self showErrorMessage:[detectedError errorMessage]];
    }
}];
```

So when I type 'k' I get response with streets and if I add next char to my text field I receive OVER_QUERY_LIMIT every time. I've tried it on simulator and devices with the same result. And it starts working again after 10-20 sec. I don't use loops or smth similar, I just want to get suggestions for input string in real time, but I can't get it because of error. What should I do to avoid it?

Comment: Go to your google developer console and increase limit of API by using paid service. or may be you are using someone Api key to your project make sure it or make new one for it

Answer (score 0):

For the web service request, use a key.

Follow this :https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start#api_key

Doc says:

> Note: Maps for Work users must include client and signature parameters with their requests instead of a key.
>       All Geocoding API applications should use an API key. Including a key in your request:
>   Allows you to monitor your application's API usage in the Google Developers Console. Enables per-key instead of **per-IP-address quota limits**. Ensures that Google can contact you about your application if necessary. The Geocoding API uses an API key to identify your application. API keys are managed through the Google APIs console. To create your key:
>   Visit the APIs console at Google Developers Console and log in with your Google Account. Click the Services link from the left-hand menu in the APIs Console, then activate the Geocoding API service. Once the service has been activated, your API key is available from the API > Access page, in the Simple API Access section. Geocoding API applications use the Key for server apps. To specify a key in your request, include it as the value of a key parameter. 
>   Note: By default, a key can be used from any server. We strongly recommend that you restrict the use of your key by IP address to servers that you administer. You can specify which IP addresses are allowed to use your API key by clicking the Edit allowed referers... link in the API console. 
>   Note: HTTPS is enforced for requests that include an API key.